# How does services like Mailchimp sign from Emails?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

When you signup to send emails from a service like Mailchimp is there anything in the domain verification email that they programmatically get in order to sign  emails FROM your domain?

OR is it simply to confirm ownership of the email address?

I am trying to write an email sending app with PHP, I've built an SMTP server and  trying to sign outbound emails from my users email id.

I'm trying to figure out how domain verification by email actually works.

Comment: Take a look at their manual. They have a section about what needs to be done to be able to send emails from a custom domain.

Comment: I mean that I am building my own service and trying to implement email signing in the same way without the user needing to add txt or SPF records. 

I was referring to them as an example- how do they sign emails just by sending a verification message to the owner of a domain?

Comment: AFAIK, they don't. To be able to use a custom domain (and for them to guarantee that the emails will work as expected), their customers need to add DKIM and SPF records to their DNS's. The problem isn't that you need to verify that the client owns the email. The problem is that the receiving mail server needs to know that your SMTP server is allowed to send emails from the clients hostname.

Comment: Agreed with the principle and we use this in our app already- Our users can add a txt record to their domain but many don't want to or don't know how- its a huge support overhead. Mailchimp and almost every other provider offers a "verify your email address" by confirming receipt of their verification email. They still reach inboxes with the from address of the user, and have decent delivery rates without the trouble of using SPF and TXT records in their domain. I'm trying to figure out how or what technique is used.